# Any pure-front-end system help me reuse html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

For exmaple, I have 3 pages with the same structure:

```
   banner  
main content
   footer
```

The `banner` and `footer` part are the same html, and `main content` are different static html .
I don't want to copy the html code for `banner` and `footer` to each page which makes the refactor of code hard. And I don't want back-end output methods. Thanks.

Comment: "And I don't want back-end output methods." Why not? You'd rather use js? Or do you want to use iframes or something? Or store your templates in a javascript file and then just `document.write(header)`? I really think the best solution is on the server side...

Comment: My first thought: use a Master Page, but I guess you don't want to do that... Next thought, put the HTML for your banner and footer into functions, put the functions into script files, include the script files in each of your pages and call them appropriately. That's dirty, dirty, dirty though...

Comment: @Wesley Murch They are simple static html files, I don't want to bother the back-end programmers for this.

Comment: Use frames. Or iframes. You won't even need JavaScript. (Seriously though, back-end methods are best for this. Are you forbidden to include the minimal back-end code that would be necessary?)

Comment: You don't have to bother anyone. 99% chance you already have php installed on your server, you can use `<?php include 'banner.html'; ?>` in a `.php` file and write the rest of it in static HTML.

Comment: Is this running on a any form of server (apache, lighty, IIS)? You don't have to bother the back end programmers for [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

Comment: @wong2 If you have back-end programmers that don't want to be bothered writing back-end programs, you're probably working in the wrong place.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Yes, but I think this is really simple thing and I'm wondering if there is a front-end method. if there is not, of course I will ask for back-end programmer

Comment: @wong2 If you don't want to use server-side code, the best way is probably to use some form of CMS or other tool that will generate static files for you by building up your components. You give it the components, "burn" a copy of the site to HTML locally, then throw that on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer so far was here:

> Use `<?php include 'banner.html'; ?>` in a .php file and write the rest of it in static HTML. – Wesley Murch Aug 17 at 7:35

Technically, it's back-end code. But, technically, if nothing goes wrong, you won't have to bother back-end programmers. Keep your reusable static HTML in one place and call it when you need it.

Otherwise, I can't quite wrap my head around the idea of reusing server-side resources *without* calling on the back-end. It's basically a paradox.